# how to add series of sql time values in java

Tags: java, sql, time

I have a ResultSet of of Time objects that are the differences between two times.  They are in the minute to second range for example "00:01:12" or "00:00:22"

How do I add these java.sql.time values together to be a sum of time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Date sumDates(String[] dateStrings, DateFormat df) {
    int secs=0, mins=0, hrs=0;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    for (int i=0; i<dateStrings.length; i++) {
        String dateString = dateStrings[i];
        Date date = (Date) df.parse(dateString);
        calendar.setTime(date);
        secs += calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        mins += calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        hrs += calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    }
    calendar.set(0, 0, 0, hrs, mins, secs);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Example of usage:

```
String[] dateStrings = { "00:01:12", "00:00:22" };
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date total = sumDates(dateStrings, df);
System.out.println(df.format(total)); //output: 00:01:34
```

Answer (score 0):

java.sql.Time is designed to represent points in time, not durations, so you can't do arithmetic with objects of that class directly.  I'm somewhat surprised there's not a java.sql analog of Duration, since some RDBMSes provide the distinction.  Anyway, you can always do it manually, with (semi-pseudo)code like this:

```
int totalSeconds = 0;
for (java.sql.Time s : myResultSet) {
    totalSeconds += s.getHours()*3600 + s.getMinutes()*60 + s.getSeconds();
}
```

Comment: Joda time does do time intervals.